# How to log in into elementary using fingerprint scanner?

Tags: greeter, hardware

I want to use a finger print reader device to log in from the Greeter(lock screen).

I tried [fprint](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint), which made it possible to use it instead of sudo password, but is it possible to unlock the elementary lockscreen with it? (I suppose fprint works in Ubuntu, but I guess that elementary uses something different for a lockscreen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1437540

It seems that it will be fixed in Loki, as you cn see the state of the bug: A patch has being requested to merge...

Comment: That's great news! Can't wait to use it in Loki! :)

Answer (score 0):

Greeter doesnt like it when you first boot. If you lock your screent though it will unlock. just not first boot.

I would like a resolution to this as well.
Would be nice to see fprint built-in and fingerprint registration on the user setup plugin.